# fengyuanchen jQuery cropper plugin - minimum crop validation

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, jquery-plugins

I am trying to impose a minimum size of the cropped data output using fengyuanchen jquery cropper plugin - https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

The plugin offers two options `minCropBoxWidth` and `minCropBoxHeight` however these only control the actual crop box on screen. As the size of the image within the cropper can be anythign (within reason) this doesnt help to ensure the size of the eventual output. Its straight forward enough to retrieve the actual size of the image (it is passed in the data argument to the `crop` function). What I am stuck on is stopping the cropping box from being reduced in size once the min width/height values have been met. I get `$(this).cropper(...).disable is not a function`

```
$('.image-preview img').cropper({
                    aspectRatio:1/1,
                    strict:true,
                    background:false,
                    guides:false,
                    autoCropArea:1,
                    rotatable:false,
                    minCropBoxWidth:20,//using these just to stop box collapsing on itself
                    minCropBoxHeight:20,
                    crop:function(data){
                        //test the new height/width
                        if(data.height < 120 || data.width < 120){
                            //try to make it stop 
                            $(this).cropper().disable(); //here be the error
                        }else{
                           var json = [
                              '{"x":' + data.x,
                              '"y":' + data.y,
                              '"height":' + data.height,
                              '"width":' + data.width + '}'
                            ].join();
                           $('#image-data').val(json);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, calling the `disable` method is done like this:

```
$(this).cropper('disable');
```

But this won't help you in what you're trying to achieve. 
Instead I'd suggest to handle the appropriate events triggered by the cropper: `dragstart.cropper` and `dragmove.cropper`. To prevent the event from finishing you can just return a false value.

Here's an example:

```
$('.img-container img').on('dragmove.cropper', function (e) {
    console.log('dragmove.cropper');

    var $cropper = $(e.target);

    // Call getData() or getImageData() or getCanvasData() or
    // whatever fits your needs
    var data = $cropper.cropper('getCropBoxData');

    console.log("data = %o", data);

    // Analyze the result
    if (data.height <= 150 || data.width <= 150) {
        console.log("Minimum size reached!");

        // Stop resize
        return false;
    }

    // Continue resize
    return true;
}).on('dragstart.cropper', function (e) {
    console.log('dragstart.cropper');

    var $cropper = $(e.target);

    // Get the same data as above 
    var data = $cropper.cropper('getCropBoxData');

    // Modify the dimensions to quit from disabled mode
    if (data.height <= 150 || data.width <= 150) {
        data.width = 151;
        data.height = 151;

        $(e.target).cropper('setCropBoxData', data);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/9r6czo65/12/)

Comment: Works, but with ugly or wrong behaviours (example: if you drag, reducing the cropBox, very fast, the cropBox will be smaller than the minWidth desired)